# Which physical/mathematical phenomena which yields the following number sequence 1,1,inf,5,6,3,3,3,3...?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to earn a date with a girl on OkCupid and I'll really appreciate it if someone can help me! Thanks. :)

Comment: This is the maximum number of regular polytopes of each dimension. I.e. There is 1 0-Dimensional polytope, 1 1-dimensional polytope, infinitely many regular polygons, 5 regular polyhedra etc.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s4TqVAbfz4 This video will give you a little bit more knowledge if you're trying to impress someone ;)

Comment: You might also impress her by learning to [post mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Yeah, tell her you're into $\LaTeX$. Report back what she says.

Comment: Amazing. Best $\LaTeX$ joke I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

Number of regular polytopes in various dimensionalities of space:

0 dimensions: just a point

1 dimension:  just a line

2 dimensions:  regular polygons with any number of sides >=3

3 dimensions:  the 5 Platonic solids

etc.